# How can I get the MySQL table with column data in the form of a list in spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, api, rest, spring-data-jpa

I have exactly such a controller and it gives orders to the repository field.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping (path="/quex")
public class CommentController {

  @Autowired
  CommentRepository repository;

  @GetMapping(path="/list")
  public List<String> getAllUser () {
  
    return repository.getUserAll();
  }
}
```

Then I defined the repository part that makes transactions on my MySQL server like this.

```
@Repository
public class CommentRepository {

  @Autowired
  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public List<String> getUserAll () {

    List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

    users.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from users", String.class));
  
    return users;
  }
}
```

I want to get it exactly in the form of the list at the bottom.

```
{
"name": "Thunder",
"lastname": "Paxis",
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question a bit? Are you trying to return an array of JSON objects from a Spring controller? I guess `queryForList` in your code is failing. You could start by reading the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate-examples-query

Comment: @Andreas I don't have a problem pulling data, I just don't know how to get a list of data in key - value form . Can you help ?

Comment: I guess your `users` table has more than one column, therfore it is not possible to map multiple columns via `queryForList` to a `String.class`. You could use however `List<Map<String,Object>> queryForList(String sql)` without a type parameter. And then simply pass that up to the controller. If you don't care that your table structure and naming is bound to the JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a POJO that matches the columns from your users tables and use it as casting.

```
public class User {
  // private Long id; // did not see it in your json but assuming it exists in DB and you would need it if select *
  private String name;
  private String lastName;

  // Getters and setters...
}
```

You can skip any column you don't want in the POJO but it needs to match the SQL query. Meaning, if you `select * from users` you need all columns but you can `select name, lastname from users` if you want just those 2.

There might also be some casing issues. Java usually uses camel case so it often confuses me if we have to use camel case for the library to match the column or not.

Anyways... Now you can update your code with:

```
@GetMapping(path="/list")
public List<User> getAllUser () {
  return repository.getUserAll();
}
```

...

```
public List<User> getUserAll () {
  List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
  users.addAll(jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from users", User.class));
  return users;
}
```

One last note, `User` might not be the best name for the class as your project probably has 10 to 15 classes with this name already in your dependencies... It will work just fine but be sure to import the correct one ;)

Comment: Thank you for the information and I just wanted to see if I can do the project for now : )

Comment: I can be mistaken but afair `queryForList` with a type parameter uses a `SingleColumnRowMapper` internally. So mapping to a `User.class` won't work. You need to use a `BeanPropertyRowMapper` with `jdbcTemplate#query`.

Just checked the Spring code which validates my assumption: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/39208eaccdd34ebcf9de813bb93516d981e1402b/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L520